# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBSDKApplicationDelegate initializeSDK]

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, facebook, fbsdk

I am working on a flutter project. Here I had to implement deeplink through notification. For this i am using flutter_facebook_app_links-2.0.0+2. I have done all the settings required for integrating the library described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/) . But my app is crashing due to

> Class FBSDKBasicUtility is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BE7882D2-54B1-4E0A-A1E2-8CB5FAF8A3D3/Runner.app/Frameworks/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics (0x102922ab0) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BE7882D2-54B1-4E0A-A1E2-8CB5FAF8A3D3/Runner.app/Runner (0x101262350). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined..

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBSDKApplicationDelegate initializeSDK]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281323750'.

Can anyone help me out to solve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at your info.plist file for iOS. It must contain the FacebookAppId, the DisplayName, and the URL Schemes.This is  Also described in Step 2 Of [Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/)

Comment: Yes I added URL Schemes already.

Comment: also check with fbAPP-ID. it should be a unique id available at your Facebook developer portal.